# Travis CI SonarCloud - How to choose what quality profile to be enabled?

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, travis-ci, sonarscanner, sonarcloud

From the Job log it looks like Travis enable all Sonar way that is available

```
...
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ruby: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
...
```

Is there a way to choose which quality profiles Travis will enable?

My repo is Ruby and I want to enable Ruby quality profile only.

Comment: Sonar way is the default Quality profile. You can create your own profile using the SonarQube UI, see the documentation. Regarding the other one's: do you need all installed plugins?

Comment: Fyi, I am using SonarCloud not (hosted) SonarQube. I will try your suggestion. I don't need other installed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can define empty quality profiles with no rules for the languages you're not interested in, and then activate those empty profiles in your project.

1. Go to your organization's page, and then the **Quality Profiles** tab
2. Click **Create**, enter a name (for example "empty"), select the language

   - You will need to repeat this for each language
3. Go to your project's page, and then **Administration / Quality Profiles**, and select the newly created "empty" quality profile for each language

If that sounds tedious, you could script it, with the help of the web API:

```
token=your-sonarcloud-token
org=your-sonarcloud-organization-key
project=your-sonarcloud-project-key

languages=(abap apex c cobol cpp cs css flex go java js jsp kotlin objc php plsql py ruby scala swift ts tsql vbnet web xml)

for lang in "${languages[@]}"; do
    params="language=$lang&name=empty&organization=$org"
    curl -u"$token:" "https://sonarcloud.io/api/qualityprofiles/create?$params" -X POST

    params="project=$project&language=$lang&qualityProfile=empty&organization=$org"
    curl -u"$token:" "https://sonarcloud.io/api/qualityprofiles/add_project?$params" -X POST
done
```

This will set the empty profile for *all* languages. So you will need to go to **Administration / Quality Profiles** of your project to set a non-empty profile for the languages you're interested in.